# assigning values to a structure after allocating memory in function

Tags: c, pointers, memory, struct

I am passing a structure pointer to a function, where memory is allocated for the structure.  Works fine.  But I cannot figure out to assign a value to that newly allocated structure inside that same function.
I thought that I had found the answer to my question in another post [Allocate memory for a pointer to a struct inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593413/allocate-memory-for-a-pointer-to-a-struct-inside-a-function/22594279#22594279)
But when I copy and compiled the answer, I got the same error.
The error is in the line: *myNameIs->name = 1; // error here says must point to class/struct/union/generic type

```
  typedef struct s_nName {
        int  name;
    }myName;

    //function for allocating the memory
    void structMemInit(myName **myNameIs)
    {
        // argument is pointer-to-pointer 
        *myNameIs = (myName *) calloc(1, sizeof(myName)); // dereference pointer to get underlying pointer

        *myNameIs->name = 1; // error here
    }


    void main(void) {

        myName *myNameIs;

        structMemInit(&myNameIs); // pass the address of your pointer

        printf("%s\n", myNameIs->name);

    }
```

Comment: You pass a "pointer to pointer", not a "pointer to `struct`" are you state. Also don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `(*myNameIs)->name = 1;`. Without the parens, it associates like `*(myNameIs->name) = 1;`.

Comment: Arrgh bet me to it :P

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are technically trying to dereference an integer. The compiler sees the expression `*myNameIs->name = 1;` as

```
*(myNameIs->name) = 1;
```

To fix this you can just add parentheses around `myNameIs` and the accompanying `*`:

```
(*myNameIs)->name = 1;
```

**A side note**

It is bad practice to use `void main()`. Instead you should be using `int main()` and its variants, and return a value to the operating system